# What to do with cheese that has fermented after vacuum packing?

Tags: cheese, vacuum

While in England two weeks ago I bought a Wensleydale cheese with cranberries that was freshly vacuum packed. Over time, the pack filled with air (without breaking the seal). Upon opening the pack, there was only a slight smell of alcohol and no visible microbial growth.

Would the cheese be safe to eat? I'm guessing the cranberries fermented a little.

Comment: Was it continuously kept in a cool place such as a refrigerator?

Comment: No. It was out at room temperature most of the time.

Comment: Did the packaging say that it was shelf stable, vacuum sealed or not?

Comment: There was no label since it was packaged directly by the cheese seller in a vacuum packing machine.